# explanation of glFrustum() compared to gluLookAt()

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, freeglut

I'm debugging a code where i want to look at a scan of a depth image, but my camera setup doesn't let me see the scan. Thus, i'm playing around with camera setups. I create a huge point at (30,120,800) and i can see it using gluLookAt. What is the according setup for glFrustum(left, right, bottom, top, near, far)? Using my setup, the point should lay exactly in the center, but i cannot see it.

```
void onDisplay()
{
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glClearColor( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glPushMatrix();
glPointSize( 1111111116.0 );
glColor3f( 0.25f, 0.907, 0.731f );
glLoadIdentity();
// Set the camera
//gluLookAt(    30.f, 120.0f, 800.f, 30.f, 120.0f, 800.f, 0.0f, 1.f,  0.0f); //works
glFrustum( 28, 32,     118,     122,   798,     802);
glBegin( GL_POINTS );


glVertex3f( 30, 120, 800 );    //30,120,800

glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
//glFinish();
//glutSwapBuffers();
glutSwapBuffers();
glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
// initialize GLUT
glutInitWindowSize(800, 800);

glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);

glutInit(&argc, argv);

glutCreateWindow("HeadPoseDemo");


glutKeyboardFunc (processSpecialKeys);

glutDisplayFunc(onDisplay);
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: To use a camera analogy `glFrustum` describes the lens on the camera (wide angle, telephoto, depth of field) but does not say where the camera is pointing.  `gluLookAt` points the camera for you.

Comment: From the opengl tutorial: By default, the camera is situated at the origin, points down the negative z-axis, and has an up-vector of (0, 1, 0). So in  http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html. With gluLookAt you move the camera to a point, you set the orientation of it and you set where the up-vector points to. The frustrum defines to which extends your camera can look to. "How close and far it can look from its position"

Comment: Thank you @Richard, could you point me to an explanation why i do see the point with `gluLookAt(30.f, 120.0f, 800.f, 30.f, 120.0f, 800.f, 0.0f, 1.f,  0.0f);` but not with `gluLookAt(0.f, 0.0f, 0.f, 30.f, 120.0f, 800.f, 0.0f, 1.f,  0.0f);`. My problem is that I want to see a point cloud and need to look at it from further away

Comment: @TobSta One question at a time please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The devil's in the details: Note how in the documentation they say

> *nearVal, farVal*
>
> Specify the **distances to** the near and far depth clipping planes. Both distances must be positive.

That's different from the wording they use for the other parameters:

> *left, right*
>
> Specify the **coordinates for** the left and right vertical clipping planes.

What you're expected to know is that you're looking along the negative z-axis. So my guess is that you're going to see your point when you change it to `glVertex3f(30.f, 120.f, -800.f);`.